# Understanding role of tangent/cotangent space changes under coordinate transformations

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, tensors

This is kind of a follow-up to the excellent answer to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/445948/general-coordinate-transformations

I want a very clear understanding of what all is going on under the hood. Let's just assume the manifold we're working with right now is just $\mathbb{R}^2$. When we do a linear transformation of a rectilinear coordinate system, it's generally taught that vector components transform like this:

$$A'^x=\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}A^x + \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}A^y\ \ ;\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ A'^y=\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x}A^x + \frac{\partial y'}{\partial y}A^y$$

For a transformation from the Cartesian system to a general curvilinear system, from what I understand, **instead of talking about how the components of $\mathbf{A}$ are related via coordinate system transformation, we have to talk about how the components *in the tangent/cotangent spaces of a particular point $P$ in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ manifold* are affected by the coordinate transformation**.

Is the above understanding correct?

Assume that the coordinate system transformation is defined by $x^i=x^i(\mathbf{x}')$ and its inverse $x'^i=x'^i(\mathbf{x})$. Suppose we have some vector with representation $\mathbf{A}=\sum_iA^i\mathbf{e}_i$ before and $\mathbf{A}=\sum_iA'^i\mathbf{e}'_i$ after, **where $\{\mathbf{e}'_i\}_i$ is the basis of the tangent space at some point $P$ *in the transformed coordinate system*** defined as:

$$\mathbf{e}'_i=\bigg(\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial x'^i}\bigg)_P$$

where the derivatives are evaluated at $P$. **Similarly the basis $\{\mathbf{e}_i\}$ of the tangent space at $P$ *in the initial coordinate system* is**:

$$\mathbf{e}_i=\bigg(\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial x^i}\bigg)_P$$

To find $A'^j$, for example, I'll need to pick the covector $\mathbf{e}'^j$ and act it on $\mathbf{A}$:

$$A'^j=\mathbf{e}'^j(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{e}'^j\bigg(\sum_iA^i\mathbf{e}_i\bigg)
=\sum_iA^i\mathbf{e}'^j(\mathbf{e}_i)=\sum_iA^i\mathbf{e}'^j\bigg(\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial x^i}\bigg)
\\=\sum_iA^i\mathbf{e}'^j\bigg(\frac{\partial\big(\sum_kx'^k\mathbf{e}'_k\big)}{\partial x^i}\bigg)
=\sum_iA^i\bigg(\frac{\partial\big(\sum_kx'^k\mathbf{e}'^j(\mathbf{e}'_k)\big)}{\partial x^i}\bigg)
\\=\sum_iA^i\bigg(\frac{\partial\big(\sum_kx'^k\delta^j_k\big)}{\partial x^i}\bigg)
=\sum_iA^i\frac{\partial x'^j}{\partial x^i}$$

I'd just like to know if the statements in bold in the above paragraphs are correct, or if there's a technical mistake or something I missed.

*Note that I've deliberately avoided dot product usage in favor of covectors acting on vectors, just to explicitly understand the interplay of tangent/cotangent spaces.*

Comment: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold (think of $\mathbb R^n$ if you wish). I think the best way to answer your question is to use the definition of the tangent space  $T_pM$ at $p\in M$ as the set of derivations on $C^{\infty}(M)$. Then the cotangent space $T^*_pM$ is just its dual space.  By expressing $p$ in two coordinate charts $(U,\varphi),\ (V,\psi)$, you can see directly how the components of arbitrary tangent vectors to $p$ transform by a simple calculation of the Jacobian matrix $\mathcal J(\psi\circ \phi^{-1}).$ Similarly, you can then calculate how the components of covectors transform.

Comment: @Matematleta: Hi, could you elaborate if possible? I'm not familiar with the terminology of coordinate charts or what $U,V,\varphi,\psi$ are supposed to mean. For reference, my background so far is introductory knowledge of tangent/cotangent spaces, and of what dual vectors are supposed to be - I guess that should be sufficient to understand a potential answer :)

Comment: @Matematleta: Also, in the middle paragraph (the one in bold), is my understanding correct?

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/521857/2451

Comment: Not sure if I get the gist of your post. As I understand it, physicists usually consider the tangent space at $p$ to be the collection of tuples that transform according to $\tilde v^i=\frac{\partial \tilde x^j}{\partial x^i}v^i$ under a change of coordinates, and the cotangent space as the collection of tuples that transform according to the rule $\omega_i=\frac{\partial \tilde x^j}{\partial x^i}\tilde \omega_j$. There is a more fundamental way to treat this idea. You can find this exposition in the book I linked in your other question.

Comment: @Matematleta: So the idea behind the question is to reconcile the transformation laws as are usually taught in Physics with a proper mathematical description. You're correct about how physicists define a tangent/cotangent space - in terms of how components transform. What I'm trying to do is understand how to **derive** those same transformation laws starting from just the mathematical definitions. The main roadblock is in the last paragraph. To find $A'^j$, I need to find $\mathbf{e}'^j(\mathbf{A})$ and thus $\mathbf{e}'^j(\mathbf{e}'_i)$. Hope that clears up the context

Comment: I think the quickest route to the transformation laws would be $1).$ Define the smooth manifold $M,\ 2).$ Define tangent vectors as derivations on $C^{\infty}(M)$  and from there, the tangent space $T_pM$ at a point $p\in M.\ 3).$ Define the cotangent space $T^*_pM$ as the dual space of $T_pM$. If you are really ambitious, go straight to the study of vector bundles. The theory of these brings into focus what is really going on. (My opinion only, of course).

Comment: @Matematleta: My bad, I didn't put enough effort earlier in the last part of the question. It's not as hard to derive the component transformation equation as I thought. I've edited the question accordingly, but still I'm not entirely sure whether the statements in bold are technically correct. I'll keep looking!

Comment: The book I linked to will help a lot, I think. There are several equivalent ways of developing the theory of tangent/cotangent spaces and they are all worth knowing-

Comment: @Matematleta: Yep! Already started looking into that book and it's really good. Thanks a lot

Comment: My apologies in advance, but I'm not sure I completely understand your concern. I don't think **we have to** is the right expression here, it is up to you how to describe transformations. It is true that tangent/cotangent spaces provide a complete machinery to understand coordinate transformations on manifolds. But, so does your first set of equations. I hope it makes sense